# Coefficient on a dummy variable

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data, linear-model

Suppose I have the following regression:
\begin{align*}
    y=\beta_0+\beta_1A+\beta_2B+\beta_3C+\beta_4(A*B)+e;
\end{align*}
where $A$ and $B$ are dummy variables, $C$ is a continuos variable and $A*B$ is a interaction.
Suppose, too, I have this other regression:
\begin{align*}
    y=\delta_0+\delta_1A+\epsilon;
\end{align*}
What is the relation between the coefficientes $(\delta_0,\delta_1)$ and the coefficientes $(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3,\beta_4)$?.